# Why is $-5^2=-25$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

If $-5^2$ is equal to $(-5)(-5)$, doesn't that mean the negatives should cancel each other out and become $25$? Why is this not the case?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: $-5^2$ means $-(5^2)=-(5)(5)=-25$. Compare with $(-5)^2$, which means $(-5)(-5)=25$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're confusing $(-5)^2$ with $-5^2$. We have $(-5)^2 = (-5)(-5) = 25$, but $-5^2 = -(5^2) = -25$.

Comment: Exponents have a higher precedence than negation. Think of it as $0-5^2$ (exponents come before subtraction).

Answer (score 9):

I'm guessing you calculated this on a calculator. Since exponentiation is ranked higher than multiplication as far as order of calculation is concerned, the calculator reads $-1\cdot 5^2$, and so calculates the $5^2$ portion before multiplying by $-1$. This is remedied by wrapping $-5$ in parentheses before evaluating. $(-5)^2$ should give you the answer you would expect.

Comment: Looked up the pneumonic. It means "parentheses, exponents, multiplication, division, addition, subtraction". That is awful and I want to kill whoever made it.

Comment: bjb I agree. That pneumonic does more bad than good

Comment: This is somewhat tangential, but the word is 'mnemonic', not 'pneumonic'.

Comment: @Unochiii I'll just remove everything in my post I said about the mnemonic and stick to what I know is right :)

Comment: @graydad, you should have left it -- you breathed new life into an old word!

Comment: I mean if you view that particular mnemonic as a harmful plague-like teaching that many young folk have drilled into their heads, pneumonic is pretty fitting!

Answer (score 6):

Parentheses are your friend. $-5^2$ actually means $-(5^2) = -25$. $-5^2$ does not mean $(-5)^2$. Think order of operations: parentheses and exponents first, then multiplication and division, then addition and subtraction. You can view $-5^2$ as being $(-1)\cdot 5^2$. Doing exponents first, you get $(-1)\cdot 25 = -25$.

Answer (score 2):

Because you forgot the parentheses. You meant to calculate $(-5)^2$ but instead calculated $-(5^2)$. When in doubt, use more parentheses than seem necessary.

---

By the way, this also applies to imaginary numbers: $(-5i)^2 = -25$, but $-(5i)^2 = 25$.